# Building add-in for outlook using python

Tags: python, outlook, office-js

need to implement add-in for outlook that will execute python code, especially read all messages and send it to python code. Found office.js - microsoft's way to develop add-in using javascript. Think I can run Python by REST API (like sending data to code written in python from office.js), but issue here is that Outlook REST API requires authorization, which doesn't work (CORS issue, expired JWT token).

Is there a way how can I achieve this?

Comment: Hey, are you working on an on-prem setup? If it is so, client-side requests using AJAX or similar libraries fail because CORS isn't supported in that server setup. [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/use-rest-api#call-the-api]

And, we highly recommend using Microsoft Graph instead of Outlook REST APIs are they will be fully decommissioned soon.
For more info, kindly check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/#outlook-rest-api-via-microsoft-graph

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT sure, I read about deprecated REST API and want to use Graph, but currently I'm facing with CORS issue as you mentioned. So in order to fix it, the server (outlook's mail server in my company) has to make my add-in address (localhost:3000) as trusted?

Comment: Can you please share the steps you are trying to make the graph call. Also if possible please share the code snippet you are trying.